# I think my question was closed incorrectly

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Recently my question on Superuser was closed for being a duplicate of another question, but I've checked that one out and what I found doesn't really help with the problems I'm facing. I've also looked elsewhere on this site for answers and just haven't found anything to help me.

Anyways, here is the link to my question:

[Issues with my computer hanging and freezing](https://superuser.com/questions/449022/issues-with-my-computer-hanging-and-freezing/449032#449032)

Comment: In my opinion, your question is overly broad. The "original" question even more so. This type of question is better handled as a community faqs, and looks like we already have one: http://superuser.com/questions/224515/how-do-i-troubleshoot-hardware-issues-related-to-a-computer-freeze-crash

Comment: Ok, I get that. Would it be alright if I opened another question, and added more detail? And if that is acceptable, what sort of detail should I add?

Comment: @Landon I would look over the community FAQ's first.  If there's a specific issue that you need more clarification then ask that.

Answer (score 4):

I know that you've already [posted a new question](https://superuser.com/questions/452774/troubles-with-procdump) which is off to a good start, but here's a little more detail on why the original question was closed.  You asked a question that has been asked hundreds, of times her on Super User.  Answering those questions day in and day out gets tiring and frustrating to regulars, especially when they're basically the same answer.

I addressed this issue here:

[The infamous "My PC is freezing" question...](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1786/the-infamous-my-pc-is-freezing-question)

> Here's my question, do we just allow each one, and help the Super User
>   along as they learn? Do we try to merge them all into a general
>   "freezing" super question and close any future questions? Or do we try
>   to use the Super User blog and post about stuff like this and then
>   close questions regarding this?

And Joel came out with a [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/) regarding it:

> When you see a question that seems like it might reflect a common
>   problem, **don’t just answer it to get a few points**. That doesn’t
>   make the Internet any better. **Instead, help us build up a library of
>   canonical questions and answers that are more generic versions of the
>   same question**, and then start closing all the exact duplicates
>
> Help us build a great library of canonical answers. If you keep seeing
>   the same form of questions, whether it’s mod_rewrite rules on Server
>   Fault, freezing computers on Super User, or how to use regular
>   expressions to parse HTML, **write a great, canonical answer, once and
>   for all. Make it community wiki so that as many other people as
>   possible can make it great.** Work really hard on writing something
>   that is clear, concise, and understandable by as wide an audience as
>   possible.

Thus was born our [canonical answers](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1856/help-create-and-maintain-community-faqs) or [community-faq](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-faq).  These are all questions that arise pretty often here on Super User, and have been given a lot of thought into asking and answering them.

So in regards to your original question, it was one of those "My computer is freezing! Help me!" questions.  We simply ask that you look at those, read through them, and then IF and ONLY IF you have any more **specific** questions go ahead and ask.